# Wordpress inline php does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a little question why my inline php code doesn't work:

If I wrote my code like this: which is very ugly btw(IMO), it works great.

```
<?php
$cat = get_terms('logietype'); 
?>
<section class="paddings">
    <div class="container-full">
        <?php


        foreach ($cat as $catVal) {
            echo "<div class='row'>";
            echo "<h2 class='logieheader'>".$catVal->name."</h2>";
            $postArg = array('post_type'=>'logie','posts_per_page'=>-1,'order'=>'desc',
                              'tax_query' => array(
                                                    array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => 'logietype',
                                                        'field' => 'term_id',
                                                        'terms' => $catVal->term_id
                                                    )
                            ));

            $getPost = new wp_query($postArg);
            global $post;

            if($getPost->have_posts()){

                    while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post();
                        echo "<div class='col-md-4 no-padding'>";
                        echo "<h3 class='logieheader'>".$post->post_title."</h3>";
                        echo "<p>".$post->post_content."</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    endwhile;

            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

But when I try this: which is much cleaner(IMO), nothing works :(

```
<?php
$cat = get_terms('logietype'); 
?>
<section class="paddings">
    <div class="container-full">

        <?php foreach ($cat as $catVal): ?>
            <div class='row'>
            <h2 class='logieheader'><?php $catVal->name ?></h2>
            <?php $postArg = array('post_type'=>'logie','posts_per_page'=>-1,'order'=>'desc',
                              'tax_query' => array(
                                                    array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => 'logietype',
                                                        'field' => 'term_id',
                                                        'terms' => $catVal->term_id
                                                    )
                            ));

            $getPost = new wp_query($postArg);
            global $post; ?>

            <?php if($getPost->have_posts()): ?>

                    <?php while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post(): ?>
                        <div class='col-md-4 no-padding'>
                        <h3 class='logieheader'><?php $post->post_title ?></h3>
                        <p><?php $post->post_content ?></p>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
</section>
```

Anyone has any idea why the one works and the other doesn't?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you (1) told us what you're trying to do, (2) highlighted what is different between code chunks, (3) explained what you mean by "nothing happens," and (4) included any error messages from your error log. Right now, your question is at risk of downvotes and being closed.

Comment: Missing echo and semicolon at `<?php $catVal->name ?>` ,`<?php $post->post_title ?>` and `<?php $post->post_content ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of the following line:

```
 <?php while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post(): ?>
                                                           ^ see this colon here
```

It should be,

```
 <?php while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Oh wauw I am stupid, forgot to actually echo in the php tags :D

Comment: @FrankLucas Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue. *Cheers!* :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you Should put semicolon after, like this:

```
<?php $catVal->name; ?>
<h3 class='logieheader'><?php $post->post_title; ?></h3>
<p><?php $post->post_content; ?></p>
```